# Error with passing data over Intent

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I'm trying to pass an ID from one class to another using intent after watching a youtube tutorial. However, it always passes over the default value of -1 rather than the value I want.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String homeTeam = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + homeTeam);

            Cursor data = myDB.getMatch(homeTeam); //get the id associated with that name
            int itemID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }
            if(itemID > -1){
                //Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ViewMatchesActivity.this, UpdateMatchActivity.class);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("MatchId", itemID);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("homeTeam",homeTeam);
                startActivity(editScreenIntent);
            }
            else{
                toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The class it goes to:

```
 //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

    //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("matchId", -1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value

    //now get the name we passed as an extra
    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("homeTeam");

    //set the text to show the current selected name
    editable_item.setText(selectedName);
```

In his tutorial, it works fine but when I try it after I edit a match, in my log it comes up with MatchId = -1 when it shouldn't be.

I'll include the method in the database also:

```
public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + MATCH_TABLE + " SET " + MATCH_HOME_TEAM_COL +
            " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + MATCH_ID_COL + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + MATCH_HOME_TEAM_COL + " = '" + oldName + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newName);
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Recieving Activity Change the code

```
 //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

    //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("MatchId", -1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value

    //now get the name we passed as an extra
    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("homeTeam");

    //set the text to show the current selected name
    editable_item.setText(selectedName);
```

You should use `MatchId` instaed of `matchID`. Java is Case Sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The key which you have passing is **MatchId** and you are fetching data from **matchId**, Which are not same.

Replace your code to

```
 selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("MatchId", -1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value
```